# Classic ASP page without any HTML but only VBScript code

Tags: asp-classic

Is it ok and possible to have a classic ASP page that only contains VBScript server-side code with zero HTML?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. Not much else to say really, outputting HTML (or anything else) is entirely optional just as it is with most server side languages.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible that you use only ASP code without writing any HTML code. In that case you will have an HTML page with no design except the output of your code.